# Reporting binary regression models

Tags: regression, logistic

For my study i used a model which had 6 independent factors that predicted a binary outcome variable (yes/no). The general assumption is that a higher score should predict a yes response.

I tested this model in two different countries to understand what predicts the outcome behaviour in each.
Should i first report the regression model which contains data from both samples to test my hypothesis regarding the basic assumption of the predictors influencing the outcome.

Then should i report the 2 seperate models for each country 
Or should i not report the first 1 and simply report the 2 separate sample models.
Also, a final qs, with regards to APA format, how do i report the results of a logistic regression in a write up?

Answer (score 1):

To decide if you need to report one, two, or all three models, you should run yet one more model.  In this new model, include a new dummy variable for the country. Include the interaction terms with the dummy variable.  If any of the interaction terms with the dummy variable or the main effect for the dummy variable is statistically significant, then this indicates that you have different models for each group.  In this case, you can simply report the two separate models.  If they are n.s., then you are justified in collapsing the two countries into one model.

Note, you can also run an omnibus model comparison test and assess if there is anything gained by adding any of the dummy variable and interactions.

As for APA format, the best strategy is to Google the title of a common APA journal (say Journal of Educational Psychology) and "logistic regression".  Then you can scan a few articles to see how those authors reported their results.

Comment: Is it appropriate to conduct a t test analysis between the 2 samples on all the predictive variables to see if there was any difference in scores as a seperate aspect- the logistic models only showed a few variables to be sig in predicting the outcome in each country

Comment: That would be a good idea to assess for possible confounding effects from any of those variables. (If they are different across the groups, this could have an impact).